# reCAPTCHA not showing

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a key pair for reCAPTCHA v2 on our staging server but today the block suddenly stopped rendering. I see the `div` with a `display:none`, no errors in the  console.
In the reCAPTCHA admin console I found this message

> We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions
>   less than 50% of the time

I don't have enough stats for this domain to see what the problem is, it's been working since we implemented it a few months ago and the code hasn't changed recently. Searching around, I tried using `async defer` with explicit render, I tried moving around the script tag after the div, I tried disabling all plugins, tried different browsers on different machines, tried generating a new key pair: none of it works.

How do we solve this problem and get our captcha working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation I got from Google's side was that too many requests were failing. We happened to be doing user tests on our side around that time so I can only assume that messed up our stats with them.

There was nothing I could do on our end (changing keys, updating domain, choosing higher security) to get it to show again, it was only a matter of waiting, a few days later the reCAPTCHA started showing again on our site.